# ActiveMQ Web Console not starting from remote Unix machine

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, activemq-classic, spring-jms

In my enterprise application, I have embedded broker and ActiveMQ starts when the application starts. The application is deployed in tomcat, now how can i view ActiveMQ web console.

The application is running on a remote unix server XXXX port..., I tried various things as suggested on Apache site but Web Console is not starting(localhost:8161/admin). I am also not able to find jetty.xml in my application.

Can anybody tell me how can i view the web console of the application. If u need any other info regarding the server then please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old web console from Apache ActiveMQ is not very flexible and is hard to get deployed outside Apache Karaf or in the standalone ActiveMQ mode.

You would need to deploy it as a WAR in Tomcat, and use use the port number that Tomcat uses, eg typically 8080. And the name of the WAR is the context-path typically. So basically deploy the old web console as any other WAR app in Tomcat, and see how far you can get.

An alternative console is hawtio, which is a modern HTML5 app that is much more flexible, and it has an ActiveMQ plugin to manage it - as well many other plugins.

- http://hawt.io/

Comment: Yeah I got your point, but once i install it as a WAR thn how the Active MQ will know that these many queues are there in my application. I can see that when my App starts it displays vm://localhost started. Basically how will i link my Application with the MQ WAR.

Comment: Yeah I dont think that this is possible/dont work/hard to do with the old console - See its doc http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html. But hawtio works. Just install the WAR and it detects AMQ out of the box, and you dont have to do anything!

Comment: @Claus..i downloaded and deployed the war file...but still i cannot see all the queues configure in my enterprise application. How will hawtio connect to my application and recognize the queues built out there. I tried using Connect to connect to remote host but that is also not working, looks like it is not having jolokia in it. I have all together different settings configured for Active MQ in my EE App. like tcp://localhost:61636. So, how can i connect to it and see all my queues and messages. Application is using ActiveMQ 5.0